# The installer does not detect network

Tags: installation

I downloaded the installation image, right to the flash drive, then boot from it.

I choose *Install Ubuntu*, and in the next window, described three recommended conditions, the last-established connection to the Internet.

So, I close with this condition the red X, that is, installer does not see a network.

But if I choose *Try Ubuntu*, the connection is established and Firefox opens the page.

I am connecting to the Internet via a network card.

What is the problem, and how can I get the installation to connect to the Internet?

P.S. distribution - ubuntu 12.04 (also tried kubuntu 12.04, ubuntu 12.10 beta1 - the result is the same)

Comment: What happens if you start the install after the connection to the net?

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options:

1. **You can proceed with the installation without connecting to the Internet.**

   While it is *recommended* to be connected to the Internet when installing Ubuntu, installation while disconnected usually works just fine. Updates will not be downloaded during installation, but other than that, Ubuntu usually installs just fine.

   After installing, when you boot into your newly installed Ubuntu system, you can update your system. You will likely be prompted automatically to do so. If not, open the Update Manager (type the first few letters of *Update Manager* into the dash and you'll be able to click the icon for it).

   Even if you were connected to the Internet and installed updates while installing Ubuntu initially, there still might be other (typically less critically important) updates to install afterwards. So updating your system after installing it is a good idea, whether or not you are connected to the Internet when you install.
2. **Since you're able to connect to the Internet after selecting *Try Ubuntu*, you can install Ubuntu while "trying" it.**

   There should be an *Install Ubuntu* icon on the desktop after you select *Try Ubuntu*. It should also appear in the Unity launcher (on the left side of the screen). If for some reason it doesn't appear in either place, you can open the dash (click the home button at the top of the launcher, or press the <kbd>Super</kbd>/<kbd>Windows</kbd> key) and search for it.

   This is probably your better option, as you'll have all the (albeit modest) benefits associated with being connected to the Internet while installing Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Дойдите до крестика, запустите нормальную сессию, запустите терминал и напишите:

ubuntu-bug ubiquity

это собирёт логи и я посмотрю что происходит.

---

Translation(not machine translated):

Continue in ubiquity until you get a red cross for missing network, then initiate a try ubuntu session, launch Terminal, and execute:

```
ubuntu-bug ubiquity
```

This will read the logs and then you can give me the details so I can see what is happening.